# Не работает функция scroll

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Не могу понять, в чем дело - не работает этот код

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    alert(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/FhRKU/

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){ 
    $('#console').html($(this).scrollTop()); //console.log(this);
});
```

`alert()` без аргумента будет выдавать ошибку:

> Not enough arguments
> [nsIDOMWindow.alert]